# How to set the current value of a Ref react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a ref to change the value of a text input when a user is typing without unnecessary rerenders. But sometimes, I want to populate the text input first.

Is there a ref.setValue function I can use? It doesn't look like it, from what I've seen of the internal members of the ref, but is there a work around?

Comment: A code example would be helpful, but I'm guessing a ref is not the right approach here. Just use a normal input with either a `value` or `defaultValue` depending on if you want the component to be controlled or uncontrolled. It's pretty unlikely you'll run into performance issues with re-renders, so it's not worth over-optimizing unless you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using TextInput's defaultValue prop